# SQL query to render similar results ignoring special characters

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

Could anyone suggest me a SQL query that can achieve the following:
The special characters `.,` `_` and `' '` should list the same results.

Example:

If you search for `123_456`, the system should also find `123456` and `123.456` and `12_3456` and `123456.7` and `_123.456`.

If you search for `12345`, the system should also find `123_456`.

Comment: Choose one `mysql` or `sql-server` ?

Comment: Considerate the function like. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Comment: use regular expression

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL LIKE % NOT SEARCHING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18630575/sql-like-not-searching)

Comment: Hover your mouse over the `SQL` tag you added to your question.  It explains that different dialects of SQL do things differently.  Until you choose `MySQL` or `SQL-Server` there will be no correct answer, because they do things differently.

Answer (score 1):

Use REPLACE and include all the special characters. Try this

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE 
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(columname,'_',''),'.',''),',','')  LIKE '%123456%'
```

Comment: Assuming SQL Server, I think he actually requires the replace to ***also*** be done on the search pattern *(specifically giving the example that searching for `'123_456'` should find `'12_3456'`...)*  After that, it's a bit ambiguous, but I think the OP needs `=` rather than `LIKE`...  `REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(field))) = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(string)))`

Answer (score 0):

I would replace all the characters, cast it as INT and filter on the FilterCol.

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
  SELECT CAST (REPLACE (REPLACE (ColA, '-', ''), '.', '') AS INT) AS 
  FilterCol, ColA
  FROM TableA
)

SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE FilterCol >= 0
```